# Blackberry 10 click event not trigger when one screen launch on top of other

Tags: events, onclick, qml, blackberry-10

```
FirstScreen.hpp 

FirstScreen.cpp 
void FirstScreen:: launchSecondScreen(){
  SecondScreen secondScreen;
}

firstscreen.qml

Page {
    Container {
        Button {
            onClicked: {
                //Launch second screen
              console.log("This will print")
              _app.launchSecondScreen();
            }
        }

    }
}

SecondScreen.hpp 

SecondScreen.cpp 
void SecondScreen:: launchThirdScreen(){
   ThirdScreen thirdScreen;
}

secondscreen.qml

Page {
    Container {
        Button {
            onClicked: {
                //Launch third screen
                console.log("This will not print")
                _app.launchThirdScreen();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

What happen once I launch second screen on top of first one click event not trigger. Please go through the link for complete project https://github.com/amityadav1984/BB10MultiscreenIssue

Because of that I have to use NavigationPane.

Comment: What's the code in SecondScreen and ThirdScreen constructors? What do they do? With the code you shared, your button click is just initializing a variable. I suspect you're trying to change the application scene, but there's no way for me to know without seeing the code.

Comment: @RogerLeblanc In words I explain, I am launching the application say with class A scene. Now I have to open another scene belongs to class B; its opening but non of the widgets having event is working. Like in Android I launch Activity A and from A I launched B but in B buttons are not clickable.

Comment: Do you `qml->setContextProperty("_app", this);` in your SecondScreen?

Comment: @RogerLeblanc in second screen even onClicked{} is not trigger for Button. qml->setContextProperty("_app", this); we use inside onClicked{}

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](‎https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as I'm not able to reproduce your issue with the very few code lines you provided.

Comment: @RogerLeblanc I put the project on GitHub please go to the link https://github.com/amityadav1984/BB10MultiscreenIssue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it really helps to get all the information needed in order to test and replicate.

First off, let me explain what's happening and then I'll explain how to fix it.

**The reason it's not working :**
You're creating `Screen2` object in a method, the object will be deleted at the end of the method. So basically, you're on `Screen1`, you click on the button which triggers your `launchScreen2` method, this method creates a `Screen2` object that sets the new visual to `Screen2.qml` and then the method delete `Screen2` object before exiting. When you click on the button on `Screen2.qml` page, the `_app` context doesn't exists anymore.

Why is it working with `Screen1` in `main.cpp` then? Because `main.cpp` will enter the main event loop before the end of the method, so `Screen1` will not be deleted until the main event loop finishes (app exit).

**How to fix :**
*1) Create `Screen2` as a pointer* :

```
Screen2* screen2 = new Screen2();
```

While this will work, be aware that you're responsible for deleting the object when you're done with it, otherwise you'll have memory leaks. A good practice is also to set parent whenever possible, that way you're sure that if the parent is deleted, all children will be too.

```
screen2->setParent(this);
```

Of course, while setting parent is a good practice, an even better practice is to delete any object as soon as they are not needed anymore, keeping your memory footprint as low as possible.

*2) Declare `Screen2` as private variable in `Screen1.hpp`, to make it a global variable.*

Note that by doing so, you need to move the code in `Screen2` constructor inside a public method that you'll have to call in `Screen1::launchScreen2()`, something like `screen2.setScene()`.

Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Its really awesome @Roger Leblanc, It's out of the box. Indeed your have a sound knowledge in Blackberry 10. Thank you very much for your support.